# I can't integrate bootstrap templates in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use a Bootstrap template for my project in CodeIgniter but I'm having trouble. I'm following a tutorial and he put this content in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|fonts|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

But I have my `.htaccess` file with this content:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and      
  leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
   RewriteBase /ci_introo/

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] 

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]   

   #RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
   # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
  </IfModule>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: you cant use template means? You can't refer the css and js of bootstrap in codeigniter. is it????

Comment: I cant use a background image from bootstrap for my homepage @kishor10d

Comment: I cant understand why you are writing such a big ```.htaccess``` while you don't need that much code.

Comment: I have a doubt that you have issue with image path in css. (```background``` as image property of css). Is there any error in console?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url() on line 106 :

Comment: line 106 : <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('img/dog.png'); ?>" alt="">

Answer (score 0):

You need to autoload the url helper in config file.

Goto `application/config/autoload.php`

find for this `$autoload['helper'] = array();`

and change it to this.

`$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

Comment: so what is the result then, is it fatal again?

Comment: Try this in your image url : ```<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/dog.png" alt="" />```

Comment: Thanks for your help @kishor10d it functions now.

Comment: Which answer is useful for you??

Answer (score 0):

You don't need .htaccess for that.
All you want to do is add url in your autoload.php

and Place this in your head.php

`application/views/head.php`

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
   //place all css u need
  </head>
```

Controller code :

```
   $this->load->view('header', $data);
```